# Scala: common practice for writing foldLeft

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In functional programmming, there are two important methods named `foldLeft` and `foldRight`. Here is the implementation of `foldRight`

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tails: List[A]) extends List[A]

 def foldRight[A, B](ls: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = ls match {
    case Nil => z
    case Cons(x, xs) => f(x, foldRight(xs, z)(f))
  }
```

And here is the implementation of `foldLeft`:

```
  @annotation.tailrec
  def foldLeft[A, B](ls: List[A], z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = ls match {
    case Nil => z
    case Cons(x, xs) => foldLeft(xs, f(z, x))(f)
  }
}
```

My question is: I read from many documents, they often put order of f function is: `f: (B, A) => B` instead of `f: (A, B) => B`. Why this definition is better? Because if we use otherwise way, it will have same signature with `foldLeft`, and it will be better.

Answer (score 3):

Because `foldLeft` "turns around" the cons structure in its traversal:

```
foldRight(Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil)), z)(f) ~> f(1, f(2, z))
                                            ^  ^
                                            A  B
foldLeft(Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil)), z)(f) ~> f(f(z, 2), 1)
                                           ^        ^
                                           B        A
```

And since it visits the conses in opposite order, the types are also traditionally flipped. Of course the arguments could be swapped, but if you have a non-commutative operation, and expect the "traditional" behaviour, you'll be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

> ...if we use otherwise way, it will have same signature with `foldLeft`, and it will be better.

No, I think that would not be better. If they had the same signature then the compiler would not be able to catch it if you intend to use one but accidentally type in the other.

The A/B order is also a handy reminder of where `B` (initial or "zero") value goes in relationship to the collection of `A` elements.

```
foldLeft: B-->>A, A, A, ...   // (f: (B, A) => B)
foldRight: ... A, A, A<<--B   // (f: (A, B) => B)
```